MiniExcel.Query<dynamic> returns System.InvalidOperationException: 'Object un-ignore properties count can't be 0' and cannot get header
I am trying to fill out a DataGridView with contents from an Excel file. I am using the MiniExcel library version 1.34.2 to do this.
When I use var records = MiniExcel.Query<dynamic>(fileName).ToList();
I get an error: Error message is: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Object un-ignore properties count can't be 0'
However when I change it to var records = MiniExcel.Query(fileName).ToList(); it works.
In the second instance it ignores the headers in the first row and used A, B, C, et al as headers. My aim was to use the first row as my headers
From what I gather that is what var records = MiniExcel.Query<dynamic>(fileName).ToList(); is supposed to do but it doesn't.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
This is what I was trying:
using MiniExcelLibs;

private void FillRecords(string fileName, int noRecords)
{
    var records = MiniExcel.Query<dynamic>(fileName).ToList();
    int countRecs = 0;
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        int rowIndex = testDataGridView.Rows.Add();
        testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["CountryName"].Value = record["name"];
        testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Alpha3"].Value = record["alpha-3"];
        testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Alpha2"].Value = record["alpha-2"];
        testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["CountryCode"].Value = record["country-code"];
        testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["CountryRegion"].Value = record["region"];
        testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["SubRegion"].Value = record["sub-region"];
        testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["IntermediateRegion"].Value = record["intermediate-region"];
        testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["RegionCode"].Value = record["region-code"];
        testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["SubRegionCode"].Value = record["sub-region-code"];
        testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["IntermediateRegionCode"].Value = record["intermediate-region-code"];
        countRecs++;
        if (noRecords > 0 && countRecs >= noRecords) return;
    }
}

I was expecting a grid with the countries and details.
I changed it to this but it is not quite ideal as I would like to know which columns I am referencing in case the excel sheet changes order or content.
private void FillRecords(string fileName, int noRecords)
{
    var records = MiniExcel.Query(fileName).ToList();
    int countRecs = 0;
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)record;
        /*foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
        {
            testListBox.Items.Add($"Header: {key}");
        }*/
        if (countRecs > 0)
        {
            int rowIndex = testDataGridView.Rows.Add();
            testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["CountryName"].Value = dict["A"];
            testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Alpha3"].Value = dict["C"];
            testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Alpha2"].Value = dict["B"];
            testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["CountryCode"].Value = dict["D"];
            testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["CountryRegion"].Value = dict["F"];
            testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["SubRegion"].Value = dict["G"];
            testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["IntermediateRegion"].Value = dict["H"];
            testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["RegionCode"].Value = dict["I"];
            testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["SubRegionCode"].Value = dict["J"];
            testDataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["IntermediateRegionCode"].Value = dict["K"];
        }
        countRecs++;
        if (noRecords > 0 && countRecs >= noRecords) return;
    }
}

This works but it gives me the first row (which was supposed to be the header) as part of my data, so I am forced to adjust for it.

Thanks @avr-girl. It's much better now. I still don't have a solution though...

I just got the same exception. Not sure if the cause is same with yours, but it went away after I changed the access modifiers of my class and its properties from internal to public.
